populating an array at compile time in C
I have some embedded C code where I want to have a list of sine values. I have done something similar in C++ using a constexpr function that return an std::array outside of the main loop:
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

#define sineListSize 100
#define sineListAmp 100

constexpr auto makeSineList() {
    std::array<int, sineListSize> list = {};

    for (int i=0; i<sineListSize; i++) {
        list[i] = sineListAmp * sin(i * 2 * M_PI / sineListSize);
    }

    return list;
}

auto sineList = makeSineList();

The way I've done it now is just the list in a separate header file, because it has 8192 elements and goes up to the signed 32-bit integer limit. It is hard to modify (I have to generate the values and copy them in manually anytime I want to change the parameters of generation) and I have to keep all the parameters in comments. How would I do something like this in C?

A side note: std::sin is constexpr only from C++26 so I doubt you actually had it working at compile-time in C++ (due to compiler support at the moment).

const int sinelist[] = { #include "output_from_program_using_sin.txt" };

Incidentally, is there a reason you truncate the values instead of rounding them to the nearest integer? Usually the latter reduces numerical errors.

@EricPostpischil Good point! No there's no reason, the generator script that I use to create the list for the C code does actually round, but then again it's a JS script that just outputs a string in C array format to be copied manually into the header file.

@wohlstad fair point My mistake. However, "I have c code" without showing it...

The classic method is you write a program that calculates the values and writes them to output in the format of a C array initialization. As part of your project’s build process, it compiles and runs that program on the build host, directing its output to a header file. That header file is included in your other sources.

It's not as elegant as doing it in the C code itself, but I guess it's the way to do it, so I'll try to implement this. As the comments have pointed out, even in C++ using constexpr has some caveats.

The best way to do this is to create a program which will output the array declaration.  Your makefile can build this program, run it to generate a header file, then that header can be included in your main program.
For example, given the following generation program called sin_list.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define sineListSize 100
#define sineListAmp 100

int main()
{
    printf("int sineList[%d] = {", sineListSize);

    for (int i=0; i<sineListSize; i++) {
        int value = lround(sineListAmp * sin(i * 2 * M_PI / sineListSize));
        if (i % 10 == 0) printf("\n    ");
        printf("%d, ", value);
    }

    printf("\n};\n");

    return 0;
}

Which outputs this:
int sineList[100] = {
    0, 6, 13, 19, 25, 31, 37, 43, 48, 54, 
    59, 64, 68, 73, 77, 81, 84, 88, 90, 93, 
    95, 97, 98, 99, 100, 100, 100, 99, 98, 97, 
    95, 93, 90, 88, 84, 81, 77, 73, 68, 64, 
    59, 54, 48, 43, 37, 31, 25, 19, 13, 6, 
    0, -6, -13, -19, -25, -31, -37, -43, -48, -54, 
    -59, -64, -68, -73, -77, -81, -84, -88, -90, -93, 
    -95, -97, -98, -99, -100, -100, -100, -99, -98, -97, 
    -95, -93, -90, -88, -84, -81, -77, -73, -68, -64, 
    -59, -54, -48, -43, -37, -31, -25, -19, -13, -6, 
};

Your makefile would look something like this:
main: main.c sin_list.h
    gcc -o main main.c

sin_list.h: sin_list
    ./sin_list > sin_list.h

sin_list: sin_list.c
    gcc -std=gnu99 -o sin_list sin_list.c -lm

Then your main program can use it:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sin_list.h"

int main()
{
    printf("sineList[1]=%d\n", sineList[1]);
    printf("sineList[2]=%d\n", sineList[2]);
    return 0;
}

